# node.js module.exports returns undefined

Tags: node.js

I'm new to node.js, and I'm trying to return a value from a function, but for some reason it's not working as planned.

In the code below, I want to return `AuthToken` from within the `Try` statement, but instead, it returns the values from outside the `Try` statement. If I delete that `return` line, then it just returns `undefined`. If I add `return AuthToken` instead then it also returns `undefined` - obviously because it hasn't completed the `Try` statement...

I've checked out a bunch of similar problems, but they haven't answered my problem.

Any suggestions?

```
"use strict";

const request = require('request'); // node package to create api request
var AuthToken;

/*
some stuff
*/

module.exports = {
    FUNC1: (param1) => {
        /*DO STUFF */
    },
    FUNC2: (param2) => {
        /*DO STUFF*/
    },
    GetAuthToken: () => {
        var options = {
            /*OPTIONS*/
        };
        try {
            request(options, (err, resp, body) => {
                if (!err) {
                    let data = JSON.parse(body);
                    AuthToken = data["accessToken"];
                    return AuthToken; // <= I expect the AuthToken to be returned here.
                } else {
                    console.log(err)
                }
            })
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
        return "Here instead"; //<= But the function is returning here instead before it's performed the request...
    },
}
```

Comment: It would appear that `err` is true or an exception was thrown.

Comment: I don't think so... console.log(err) is not hit in either occasion.

Comment: try `exports={...}` instead of `module.exports={...}`.. if that doesn't work, `exports.exportName` for each one SHOULD work(i experience no errors using that)

Comment: `exports = {...}` results in: `GetAuthToken is not a function` from the parent.
and `exports.exportName` results in `undefined` as well. I'm assuming you're referring to something like the 'Exporting Multiple Methods and Values
' example here: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured out that the request function is an asynchronous and so needs to be called with an async function.

I took the example code from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and modified it for my purposes.